# Show average difference between two time fields as MM:SS in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, datediff

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have several rows of start_time and end_time. I want to calculate the average difference between these two times in a MM:SS format.

```
start_time | end_time     
10:15:30   | 10:15:45     
10:45:00   | 10:47:30
```

Row 1 would be a difference of 00:15, and row 2 would be a difference of 02:30. The average of the entire dataset would be 01:23 (1 minute and 23 seconds).

The code I'm using looks like the following, but only returns an integer.

```
AVG(DATEDIFF(MI,start_time,end_time))
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but you should use `DateDiff()` to get the average number of *seconds* between the two fields, rather than the average number of *minutes*.

With `SQL Server 2008 R2`, you don't have access to [`TIMEFROMPARTS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which would simplify the display greatly, so you'll have to convert this into a `VARCHAR` to get the format you want.

```
;With AverageSeconds As
(
    Select  Avg(DateDiff(Second, Start_Time, End_Time))) AvgSec
    From    YourTable
)
Select  Right('00' + Convert(Varchar, (AvgSec / 60)), 2) 
             + ':' 
      + Right('00' + Convert(Varchar, (AvgSec % 60)), 2)
From    AverageSeconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dates in unixtimestamp and then convert the seconds in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```
right(convert(varchar(20), Dateadd(second, Avg(Datediff(second, Start_Time, End_Time)), 0), 120), 5)
```